# How to make the visible command line longer?

Tags: linux, command-line, shell

I have a machine that running customized linux, and I login into the system by PuTTY.

It turned out I'm using `bash`. And the `PS1` is

```
sh-4.1# echo $PS1
\s-\v\$
```

when I type following:

```
sh-4.1# ls a very long path i will not be able to see the rest of the command line
```

I will see

```
sh-4.1#
< i will not be able to see the rest of the command line
```

I can use left arrow key to move forward:

```
sh-4.1# ls a very long path i will not be able to see the rest of the command >
```

This is very inconvenience as you have to move cursor to see rest of the command line.

How can I show the whole command line?

Comment: Not sure this will help someone who knows or not, but does the `sh-4.1#` mean that you are using `bash` (my guess is the shell you use may matter)?

Answer (score 2):

No one uses `sh` anymore, it's always a symlink to the distro-specific default shell (`ash`, `ksh`, `bash`, `dash`, `zsh`, etc.). You can check with`readlink -e $(which sh)`

Are you using a `Virtual Terminal` or a terminal emulator such as `gnome-terminal`, `xterm`, `konsole`, etc.?

In any case, here's a trick: Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to initialize an editor (set by the environmental variable `EDITOR`) then save & exit and your long command will be executed.

You may wish to change the default editor using `export EDITOR="nano -w"`

Source: [Commandlinefu - Rapidly invoke an editor to write a long, complex, or tricky command](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1446/rapidly-invoke-an-editor-to-write-a-long-complex-or-tricky-command)

Comment: `readlink -e $(which sh)` shows that I'm using `bash`. Good point that I can use editor for command line edit, but when I use arrow key to view my history, I still can't see the whole line.

Comment: I had a strong suspicion it was BASH based on the 4.1 version number. Please post the value of your `PS1` environmental variable. That is the likely culprit for the line not wrapping to the next line. Additionally, update the question to specify which terminal program you are using; you might have to turn on **word-wrap**

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be anything funky going on inside your **PS1** variable, so turning focus away from which shell you are using.

`PuTTY`, huh? A quick search turned up a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/puttycyg/issues/detail?id=59) regarding wrapping. I use [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) on the occasion I'm forced to use Windows (the horror).

However, fired up a VM and lo-and-behold `Auto wrap mode initially on` is enabled by default and it actually works. Do you have this setting enabled?

[image: putty wordwrap]

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to enter the path in one go, I might suggest changing the prompt. If you don't mind going back to bash, you could add a newline near the end of the PS1 variable definition, which would move the boilerplate to a separate line, thus giving you more of the line to work with. This would be done by editing your `.bashrc`, like so:

```
# Original line from ~/.bashrc:
PS1='\s-\v# '
# ^^ prints "bash-4.2# _" as the prompt on my system
# (Ignore parens, underscore shows cursor position)
# or insert '\n':
PS1='\s-\v\n# '
#         ^^ newline, now prints
# "bash-4.2
#  # _"
```

The downside to this is that your prompt now takes up more screen real estate, and, depending on your original prompt, might only give you a few more characters to work with per line.

Having said that, is it really mandatory that the path be entered at once? It could be worth `cd`ing down a few levels (since you already know their location from the path) then running `ls` or whatever else.